# component data vs its props in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The official documentation says that there could be a `data` and a `props` option in a component.

For me it seems a sort of excessive functionality.

Why do I need both properties and data in my component? Which goals they are aimed?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Properties are meant to be propagated and managed from parent components, while data is the component internal state (which the component is responsible for).

This concept is taken from React as far as i know, and it works pretty well.
https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md

Comment: So is a prop more of a one-to-one binding between the parent and the child ("html element" -- and is the child always an html element?)? Whereas the `data` kind of belongs to the entire instance? 

Sorry for the reply on a year-old [accepted] answer, but you've come the closest to helping me to understand the OP's question as well.

Comment: Yes, props are passed from parent to child, in a one-direction binding (the child cannot modify those values). The data fields are set by the component that declares them (can be modified) and are passed to sub-components as properties. Hope it helps, components are bits of (html + css + js) that are self-contained / independent, and can be added to a page, as long as they receive their required props.

Comment: Right, similar to Evan's answer: Both data and props are reactive, but data is more like "my own state" and props is "I expect to get this from my parent."

Comment: I understand what it does however, I don't really know why I'd ever use a `prop` instead of a variable in `data` and using a mustache to display that variable. The only thing I can think is if I wanted specific child elements to have a piece of information that won't display in their text content, but will use in some other capacity. It's been years since this post was made. I apologize for bringing it back from the dead but I'm struggling to understand `props` usefulness.

Comment: You can also display props using mustaches, props are managed by the parent component leaves you with state that is propagated to children meaning you can encapsulate components with unidirectional flow of data, search react data flow, its a well known pattern