# How to change name of Props on Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to VueJS and trying to follow v-model implementation on the component as 
[example here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/)

```
<template>
    <div class="date-picker">
        Month: <input type="number" ref="monthPicker" :value="value.month" @input="updateDate()" />
        Year: <input type="number" ref="yearPicker" :value="value.year" @input="updateDate()" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['value'],

        methods: {
            updateDate() {
                this.$emit('input', {
                    month: +this.$refs.monthPicker.value,
                    year: +this.$refs.yearPicker.value
                })
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

On parent:

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <date-picker v-model="date"></date-picker>
        <p>
            Month: {{date.month}}
            Year: {{date.year}}
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import DatePicker from './DatePicker.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            DatePicker
        },

        data() {
            return {
                date: {
                    month: 1,
                    year: 2017
                }
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

I wonder why I can't change the name of props: ['value'] to  props: ['abc']
and change

```
Month: <input type="number" ref="monthPicker" :value="abc.month" @input="updateDate()" />
```

I got an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [component data vs its props in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548434/component-data-vs-its-props-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is a side effect of using `props: ['value']`.

If you change the props definition to:

```
  props: {
    abc: {
      type: Date,
      default: () => new Date()
    }
  },
```

you'll see that you can change the prop name to whatever you like.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o5uLxdhs/13/

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the attribute in its parent-component?

parentComponent:

```
 <template>
  <div id="parent">
   <div is="test" :abc="YearMonth" @input="receiveValueFromChild"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import test from "./test.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    test: test
  },
  name: "index",
  data() {
    return {
      YearMonth: { month: 1, year: 2018 }
    };
  },
  methods: {    
    receiveValueFromChild: function(val) { //here will be toggled by childComponent
      console.log(val);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

childCompoent:

```
<template>
    <div class="date-picker">
        <span>Month: </span><input type="number" v-model="abc.month" @input="updateDate()" />
        <span>Year: </span><input type="number" v-model="abc.year" @input="updateDate()" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["abc"],

  methods: {
    updateDate() {
      this.$emit("input", { //sent value to parentComponent
        month: this.abc.month,
        year: this.abc.year
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I've updated the post with Parent call. v-model receives the init value, how can I make a change in this case. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my Answer.  And maybe you could using watch: { abc:function(val){}} instead of  listen updateDate() function.